# Sort unanswered questions of category "my tags" by date?

Tags: support

When I click on "questions" --> "unanswered questions" --> "my tags", I always get to see the oldest unanswered question on top. These questions have over 1000 Views...

Is there possibility to show the newest unanswered questions from "my tags" only?
Also i do not get it how these questions are sorted. If I jump to the last page, these questions are not the latest questions.

So how do you search for new questions regarding your favorite tags?